# jQuery virtual keyboard types backwards on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, virtual-keyboard

I am using [this](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/) plugin for my one of application. It works perfectly on browsers , But when I am tried to test applicationn in iPad. The keyborad types backwords. For example if I type "abc" it returns with "cba". Any thing wrong with my configuration ? Here is my js code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $.keyboard.keyaction.cancel = function(base) {

        $('.text').val('');

    };
    $.keyboard.keyaction.search = function(base) {
        //code to manupulate after search is pressed
        a=$("#searchbox").val();
        window.location='/profiles/search_results/?keywords='+ a;
    };


    $('.text').keyboard({ 

        display: { 
            'bksp'   :  "  \u2190  ", 
            'accept' : 'accept', 
            'default': 'ABC', 
            'meta1'  : '.?123', 
            'meta2'  : '#+=' 
        }, 
        usePreview: false,
        layout: 'custom', 
        alwaysOpen   : true,
        autoAccept : true,
        position: {
            of: '.form',
            my: 'center top',
            at: 'center bottom',
            offset: '0 50'
        },


        customLayout: { 

            'default': [ 
                '` 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - ',
                ' q w e r t y u i o p {bksp}', 
                'a s d f g h j k l \'', 
                '{s} z x c v b n m , . @', 
                '{cancel!!} {space} {search!!}' 
            ], 
            'shift': [ 
                '` 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - ',
                ' Q W E R T Y U I O P {bksp}', 
                'A S D F G H J K L \'', 
                '{s} Z X C V B N M , . @', 
                '{cancel!!} {space} {search!!}' 
            ], 
            'meta1': [ 
                '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 {bksp}', 
                '- / : ; ( ) \u20ac & @ {enter}', 
                '{meta2} . , ? ! \' " {meta2}', 
                '{default} {space} {default} {accept}' 
            ], 
            'meta2': [ 
                '[ ] { } # % ^ * + = {bksp}', 
                '_ \\ | ~ < > $ \u00a3 \u00a5 {enter}', 
                '{meta1} . , ? ! \' " {meta1}', 
                '{default} {space} {default} {accept}' 
            ] 

        } ,
        display: {
            'panic' : 'cancel!', // don't use !! here  
        },

    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: I believe this is one of the [known problems](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard#known-problems) with Safari & locked inputs.

Comment: Make sure you are using a "text" or "search" type of input, [other HTML5 types do not report a caret position](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/241). Also, please make sure you are using the newest version of the plugin, jQuery & jQuery UI... `position.offset` is no longer supported in the current version of jQuery UI.